# Remote controlled screenshare

Tags: display, slack

I search for an extension to Slack that both can share my screen and let a user control my desktop with a mouse or keyboard. So far I only found screen sharing applications

Answer (score -1):

On your device, you can try searching up **Remote Desktop Connection** and running it, however, the other device you will want to connect to will have to have this app.

The **Remote Desktop Connection** app should already be installed into your system, if not, you can install it here: ms-settings:remotedesktop?activationSource=SMC-IA-4028379

Other options are:

```
- TeamViewer
- AnyDesk
- SplashTop...
```

Comment: Should be a comment as software recommendations are off topic here.